# React with Google Maps @react-google-maps/api google.maps.Marker is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps-api

I have been running @react-google-maps/api for a project number of years. Since 21st February 2024 I have been getting a deprecation warning:

```
As of February 21st, 2024, google.maps.Marker is deprecated. Please use google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement instead. Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations for deprecation details.
```

What I am hoping to do is to be able to update my code to reflect the changes. I was hoping to find the answers in the documentation. But the official documentation from the NPM repo seems to be broken:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api - scroll down to the reference to the official documentation
```

I have tried to look on Stackoverflow and also Googled out the issue but I did not find any answers.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

I am currently drawing my markers like this:

```
  drawMarker = () => {
      return <Marker
      position={{
        lat: this.state.lat,
        lng: this.state.lng
      }}
      icon={
        // @ts-expect-error
        new window.google.maps.MarkerImage(
          markerPosition,
          null, /* size is determined at runtime */
          null, /* origin is 0,0 */
          null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
          new window.google.maps.Size(48, 48)
        )
      }
    >
    </Marker>
  }
```

I have tried to replace the MarkerImage with the new AdvancedMarkerElement, but I am just getting a whole bunch of errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AdvancedMarkerElement')
```

I am stuck. Does anyone know a solution to this OR maybe know some other library that has all the features of `@react-google-maps/api` and has this problem resolved?

Comment: FYI: This issue is currently being discussed on the [github page](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/3337) of the project.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but if you work with functional components (and not class based) you can import MarkerF instead of Marker: import {MarkerF} from '@react-google-maps/api

Answer (score 0):

I saw that one comment mentioned that:
`Not sure if this is helpful but if you work with functional components (and not class based) you can import MarkerF instead of Marker: import {MarkerF} from '@react-google-maps/api`.
And I tried with it but still got the warning message.

### Discussions

[Marker will be discontinued on February 21, 2024](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/3337)

[21st, 2024, google.maps.Marker is deprecated](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/3343)